# How to Program for an Atlas Scientific Temperature and pH probe

Tags: sensor

I bought some part from Atlas Scientific for my thesis:

http://www.atlas-scientific.com/product_pages/probes/ph_probe.html?

http://www.atlas-scientific.com/product_pages/probes/env-tmp-d.html

http://www.atlas-scientific.com/product_pages/components/raspberry_pi.html

On the product data sheet one can find the following reference:

[image]
[image]
[image]

and the following sample code was given:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import serial

print "Welcome to the Atlas Scientific Raspberry Pi example."

usbport = '/dev/ttyAMA0'
ser = serial.Serial(usbport, 9600)

# turn on the LEDs
ser.write("L,1\r")
ser.write("C,1\r")

line = ""

while True:
    data = ser.read()
       if(data == "\r"):
             print "Received from sensor:" + line
             line = ""
       else:
             line = line + data
```

I really have no idea where to start. I just really needed the reading from the probe but I have no previous experience on using sensors and probes. I hope someone could help me. I already sent an email to the manufacturer but 4 days past no sample  codes or other reference material can be provided. All these will run on a raspberry pi using a raspberry pi shield that I also bought from Atlas Scientific.

Here is the setup using a Raspberry Pi3

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That script looks like it should spit out a stream of sensor readings. What happens when you run it?

Comment: It outputs "Welcome to the Atlas Scientific Raspberry Pi example." and shifts the cursor to the bottom right part.

Comment: What Pi are you using. AFAIK `/dev/ttyAMA0` is used by Bluetooth on Pi3. This really isn't a Pi question - it is also far too broad.

Comment: The script looks right, but it's likely that you're using the wrong address for your USB sensor per Milliways comment. See instructions [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/usb/README.md) for some guidance on identifying your device correctly.

Comment: I added an image of the setup using raspberry pi 3